# spring boot test h2 data.sql wrong locale date format

Tags: date, spring-boot, testing, locale, h2

I have a spring boot app with the file data.sql containing these DML commands:

> insert into example (id, created) values (1, to_date('01-JAN-18',
> 'DD-MON-RR'));
>
> insert into example (id, created) values (2, to_date('01-JAN-18', 'DD-MON-RR'));

Spring boot tests will fail after loading of spring context because of following error:

> Function "TO_DATE": Invalid date format: " Tried to parse one of
> '[dÚc., juin, mai, fÚvr., mars, ao¹t, nov., janv., avr., juil., sept.,
> oct.]' but failed

This problem was caused after I upgraded spring-boot but previously it worked correctly in version 2.0 ie. there in h2 was used default locale date as english (01-JAN-18), not germany.

Where can be the root problem or is there any advice how to set default language for h2 database (it probably uses germany as default due to locale settings on OS)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be solved by the change of calendar/date mask like this:

```
insert into example (id, created) values (2, to_date('01-01-18', 'DD-MM-RR'));
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is, Spring boot picks the data format as per your locale setting in your Operating System.

I faced the same error, and i changed the region in my windows machine and then all works.
in windows go to Control Panel >Clock and Region > change date time or number format and then change the format to English US (or what ever you want).